# How to color path levels using bashrc?

Tags: bash, colors, terminal, ps1

In my `~/.bashrc` I have

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;39m\]\u@\h:\[\033[0;32m\]\w\$\[\033[00m\] "
```

which changes the current working directory's path color into a green color. Is it possible to color each path level with a different color using bashrc? For example, if I navigate to

```
cd /usr/share/color
me@server4:/usr/share/color$
```

I want the `/usr` be red, the `/share` be green, the `/color` be blue, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [external commands in the prompt](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x279.html) each time the prompt is displayed, so everything is possible.